# escape quotes in jquery selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below how do I escape the double quotes in `"`myClass`"`

I tried `\"`myClass`\"`  but its not working

```
var s = '<span onclick="$($(this).text()).addClass("myClass")">test</span>';
```

Comment: @AmitAgrawal, '<span onclick="$($(this).text()).addClass('

Comment: @AmitAgrawal This breaks the string - it is encased in single quotes.

Comment: wont work cant have  the ' in side the '  thats why I need to escaspe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Billy Matthews said, but here's the actual example:

```
var s = '<span onclick="$($(this).text()).addClass(&quot;myClass&quot;)">test</span>';
```

`&quot;` fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, that's a serious misuse of jQuery power. The sensible way to do it would be something like this:

```
var s = $("<span>test</span>");
s.on("click", function(){
    $($(this).text()).addClass("myClass");
});
```

Comment: Yea. I like this better. It's definitely a much cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `&quot;`

BUT, that's still wrong, as this will put double quotes inside your double quoted onclick. Use `&apos;` instead for a single quote.

Comment: That should actually still work (just using &quot;) as that is how to escape in HTML. You shouldn't have to use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To escape quotes in an HTML attribute, use `&quot;`.